# How to show back button when using $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I set to show back button on nav-bar. However, when the user tries to enter an unauthenticated page, s/he is directed to login page. After successful authentication, user is directed to the page that s/he wanted to go in first place. However, instead of showing a back button, menu button is shown on the screen. How can I manage to add that?

- **Current Page ==> Home 
   Clicks ==> PrivateArea button**
- **Not authenticated, so redirected to Login page 
   Current Page ==> Login 
   Enters credentials**
- **Authenticated, redirected to PrivateArea page 
   Current Page ==> PrivateArea**

I used 
`$state.go($stateParams.nextState.name, {}, {relative: $stateParams.fromState.name});` 
but didn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please provide more code: you html template and full controller code and router settings object

Comment: are you using named views? if so, why not setting a nav-bar one and filling it accordingly?

Comment: PrivateArea and Home have named views, but Login doesn't.